# Source of twitter bootstratp, :: in front of -webkit-input-placeholder - is that a typo?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, placeholder

Twitter bootstrap.css has such a code:

```
:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
```

The question is about `::` in front of `-webkit-input-placeholder`. Why two `::` and what is that for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::` denotes a pseudo-element (e.g. `::before` and `::after`). `:` denotes a pseudo-class (e.g. `:link` and `:hover`). It's just a naming convention to differentiate between pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes. IE8 and below do NOT support the `::` convention.

Here's an explanation of these two directly from the W3C spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-elements

Answer (score 2):

`:` is for a pseudo-class.  This is a modification of an existing element.  `:hover`, for instance, represents the same element but with your mouse pointer over it.  `:focus` is when the cursor is in a form element.

`::` is for pseudo-elements, which are not directly part of the element you are styling.  Instead, they are elements that don't exist on the DOM but can be styled anyway.  `::after` is a good example of this since you can create style an element which doesn't really exist with it.

However, per usual, there appears to be some gray area of misinterpretation from browser vendors.  IE and Firefox seem to believe the placeholder is a pseudo-class where webkit treats it like a pseudo-element.

This also changes how it's styled too though, it's not just syntax.
Check this out in Chrome and Firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/UxAY6/

When that fiddle is viewed in webkit, the red border is *inside* the text field.  It's styling the placeholder pseudo-element *inside* the text field.  But it Firefox it's a pseudo-class of the input element, so the border applies to the text field while it is showing the placeholder.